# Flutter Firebase Cloud Messaging. How to signal the background handler is finished?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've got Data messages appearing beautifully in the background via FCM in Flutter(Android). I then process the message and finish my tasks everything works great.

I use:

`FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage`

This onBackgroundMessage handler is async and I await a sequence of calls.

I would have assumed once the future is completed it would suspend everything and the app would go back to sleep.

However if I create `Stream.periodic` as part of the background handler and output a value it seems to keep going even through I've completed the onBackgroundMessage handler.

**So the question is:**

What's the correct way to tell flutter I'm finished so it kills the background isolate?

Is it detecting my leaked Stream subscription and not killing me?

Is there a way to forcefully kill it?

Thanks :)